# Ionic Console/Print messages for debugging

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Is there a way to print messages to console (npm console) when running ionic serve --devapp ?

I'm using ionicv3.

I run in my cmd prompt:

`ionic serve --devapp`

It opens up the port, I connect to it using devapp on my phone, but I'm unable to see the messages in this console using console.log(message).

Here is what I'm doing:

```
let val = this.manualFramerate;
console.log(val);
```

I can't use it in browser because I'm using Bluetooth ble in this app, so I need to run it in my phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/developer-resources/developer-tips/#debugging-ios-safari if you want to see the debug logs when running on your device using safari and https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/developer-resources/developer-tips/#debugging-android-chrome for chrome

On chrome go to chrome://inspect/#devices for USB debugging

Safari

1. On iOS device enable Web Inspector Settings->Safari->Advanced
2. Show develop menu in menu bar under Safari->Preferences->Advanced
3. Develop->your device->inspector

If you must have them in a console instead of a browser you can follow this https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/3169#issuecomment-477164676

Comment: Thanks Garrett, but I can't use the this method (browser) because I'm trying to debug an app built to use bluetooth and I can't use my computer bluetooth (somehow Ionic does not accept it)